# How to pass C# datatable to mysql's stored procedure parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, datatable

I have data-table form C# (ASP.NET) side and I want to pass that data table to procedure's parameter in mysql and that hole data table dump to the temporary table in mysql

How can I achieve it in mysql ?

Please let me know !!!!

Thank you,

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TYPE members_table_type AS TABLE
(
    mem_username VARCHAR(25),
    mem_firstname VARCHAR(25),
    mem_lastname VARCHAR(25)
);

CREATE STORED PROCEDURE insert_members
@members members_table_type
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.members 
    (mem_username, mem_firstname, mem_lastname)
    SELECT mem_username, mem_firstname, mem_lastname FROM @members;
END


In .NET:
DataTable members = new DataTable();
members.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("mem_username", typeof(string)));
members.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("mem_firstname", typeof(string)));
members.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("mem_lastname", typeof(string)));

DataRow row = members.NewRow();
row["mem_username"] = "test";
row["mem_firstname"] = "test";
row["mem_lastname"] = "test";
members.Rows.Add(row);

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert_members");
command.Parameters.Add(members, SqlDbType.Structured);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: You cannot. MySQL doesn't have user-defined types.

Comment: that will possible using Sql Server , not using MySql

Comment: oh sorry yes this is for sql server